# Shared object among different requests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5

I'm working with .NET 3.5 with a simple handler for http requests. Right now, on each http request my handler opens a tcp connection with 3 remote servers in order to receive some information from them. Then closes the sockets and writes the server status back to Context.Response.

However, I would prefer to have a separate object that every 5 minutes connects to the remote servers via tcp, gets the information and keeps it. So the HttpRequest, on each request would be much faster just asking this object for the information.

So my questions here are, how to keep a shared global object in memory all the time that can also "wake" an do those tcp connections even when no http requests are coming and have the object accesible to the http request handler.

Comment: You could have a Windows Service running for that, and write the data to a file somewhere the ASP application can read it.

Comment: what about a request arriving right when the file is being written? also, i'm not sure if that's the best way ?

Comment: Then wait a little while until the file is readable.

Comment: Or, if you have a database available, you could get the Windows Service to write to that. You could devise a scheme whereby more than one set of data is stored and, only once all three remote servers have been queried, the new data is marked as valid and the old data as invalid in one transaction, then deleted at some later time. Formulate the query from ASP to include something that amounts to `AND DataValid = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

A service may be overkill for this.

You can create a global object in your application start and have it create a background thread that does the query every 5 minutes.  Take the response (or what you process from the response) and put it into a separate class, creating a new instance of that class with each response, and use `System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange` to replace a static instance each time the response is retrieved.  When you want to look the the response, simply copy a reference the static instance to a stack reference and you will have the most recent data.

Keep in mind, however, that ASP.NET will kill your application whenever there are no requests for a certain amount of time (idle time), so your application will stop and restart, causing your global object to get destroyed and recreated.

You may read elsewhere that you can't or shouldn't do background stuff in ASP.NET, but that's not true--you just have to understand the implications.  I have similar code to the following example working on an ASP.NET site that handles over 1000 req/sec peak (across multiple servers).

For example, in global.asax.cs:

```
    public class BackgroundResult
    {
        public string Response; // for simplicity, just use a public field for this example--for a real implementation, public fields are probably bad
    }
    class BackgroundQuery
    {
        private BackgroundResult _result;   // interlocked
        private readonly Thread _thread;

        public BackgroundQuery()
        {
            _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BackgroundThread));
            _thread.IsBackground = true; // allow the application to shut down without errors even while this thread is still running
            _thread.Name = "Background Query Thread";
            _thread.Start();

            // maybe you want to get the first result here immediately??  Otherwise, the first result may not be available for a bit
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the latest result.  Note that the result could change at any time, so do expect to reference this directly and get the same object back every time--for example, if you write code like: if (LatestResult.IsFoo) { LatestResult.Bar }, the object returned to check IsFoo could be different from the one used to get the Bar property.
        /// </summary>
        public BackgroundResult LatestResult { get { return _result; } }

        private void BackgroundThread()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/samplepath?query=query");
                        request.Method = "GET";
                        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                // get what I need here (just the entire contents as a string for this example)
                                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                // put it into the results
                                BackgroundResult backgroundResult = new BackgroundResult { Response = result };
                                System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref _result, backgroundResult);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // the request failed--cath here and notify us somehow, but keep looping
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Exception doing background web request:" + ex.ToString());
                    }
                    // wait for five minutes before we query again.  Note that this is five minutes between the END of one request and the start of another--if you want 5 minutes between the START of each request, this will need to change a little.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // we need to get notified of this error here somehow by logging it or something...
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Error in BackgroundQuery.BackgroundThread:" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    private static BackgroundQuery _BackgroundQuerier;  // set only during application startup

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // other initialization here...
        _BackgroundQuerier = new BackgroundQuery();
        // get the value here (it may or may not be set quite yet at this point)
        BackgroundResult result = _BackgroundQuerier.LatestResult;
        // other initialization here...
    }
```